# Apple PowerMac G5 Dual Processor PowerPC G5 video card issues

Tags: mac

Just got this G5 and hooked it up to my Sceptre VGA monitor via 4 way KVM. Only get the option for 800x600 resolution. The monitor is newer than the Mac. Says it has a 256 MB video card installed (AGP). I am using a VGA to DVI converter (again via KVM switch) could this be the issue? Do I have to use an Apple monitor? Thanks for any leads!

Comment: What happens when you click 'Detect Displays' under the Displays system preference?

Answer (score 0):

The Mac is not detecting the display's capabilities, probably due to the KVM, so it is settling for a safe default resolution. If you plug the display directly into the G5, I expect you will get the full list of possible resolutions.

Comment: Thanks.. I tried that and it still 800 x 600. Only option to choose from. Can you edit a conf file as you can in Linux? to add other resolutions?

Comment: I has to be something to do with the DVI to VGA adapter then. What ports does the G5 have on the video card? DVI and ADC? It really should be able to handle a wide range of resolutions without any tinkering unless something is wrong with the connection or the card doesn't have the proper drivers.